# Mesos Agent can not access sandbox from UI

Tags: mesos

I can not access Sandbox logs nor I can see any task in a new agent that I've added to the cluster.

This is the error: 
[Mesos UI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gy0o.png)

The new agent is detected and the bootstrapping it's okay with the ip and the hostname correctly configured:

"/usr/sbin/mesos-slave --hostname=mss4 --ip=10.32.8.160 --no-systemd_enable_support --work_dir=/tmp/mesos"

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Somebody could help me? It's very frustating connect to the machine and go to the logs path (/tmp/mesos/....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research...I hadn't in my hosts file the entry for that machine :(
Resolved.